# How to prove that the column space of AB is a subset or equal to the column space of A

Tags: self-learning, matrices, linear-algebra

This following problem is a property of column space in my Textbook which I am trying to prove.

**Problem:** For any $A$ and $B$, $C(AB) \subseteq C(A)$.

My approach:

Let us consider $A \in R^{m \times n}$, $B \in R^{n \times m}$, and $AB \in R^{m \times m}$.

If $z \in C(AB)$, then $z=AB x $, where $x \in R^m$.

Let $y \in C(B)$, then $y=B x $, where $x \in R^m$.

This implies $z = ABx = Ay$, where $y \in R^n$ and thus $z \in C(A)$

From the above argument, we can write $C(AB) \subset C(A)$.

**My question:**

- How can I prove the subset and **equality**?
- If possible, please explain the notion of **subset**, **subset and equality** in regards to vector space. That would be really helpful.

**Note:** This is not an exam/assignment question.

Comment: Under what conditions does equality occur?

Comment: Yes, I did not get how to prove with the condition when equality occurs. The arguments that I made are correct?

Comment: That was meant has a hint. For example, consider $B=I$ when $A,B$ are square. Are there similar examples for rectangular matrices? Note that is subset OR equality, like less than OR equal to. Your arguments so far are sound.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My understanding is when the $rank(AB) = rank(A)$, then the $C(AB) = C(A)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.
In the above argument, when I showed that $z \in C(AB)$ that also implies $z \in C(A)$, does that also imply $C(AB) \subseteq C(A)$?

Comment: It's does not imply the equality because $B$ doesn't necessarily have full column rank. But it does imply subset. Equality only happens under the condition you mention, or equivalently, when $B$ has full column rank.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Thanks for making that statement, this is not mentioned in the textbook. So, does that mean that the property: For any $A$ and $B$, $C(AB) \subseteq C(A)$ holds [subset holds even if $B$ is not of full column rank] when $B$ is of full column rank?

Comment: I'm confused by your restatement? The statement is that for any $A$ and $B$, the column space of $AB$ is either a subset of OR equal to the column space of $A$, with equality only occurring when $B$ has column rank equal to that of $A$. I realized full rank isn't required unless $A$ has full column rank.

Comment: I stated the problem at the beginning of my question. Thanks again.